# What's the magic of the "sudo su"?

Tags: sudo, su

```
[demo@PHP_DEV_57 ~]$ sudo su
[root@PHP_DEV_57 www]#
```

Why I can switch to root by simply `sudo su`, what's the difference between sudo and su?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo` allows one user to run commands with the permissions of another user. By default, on most systems, some users are allowed to use sudo to run commands as root. `su` requires a user's password to log in as that user, unless it is run by root. Thus, `sudo su` allows you to pretend to be root in order to log in as root without root's password.

PS: `sudo -i` is recommended over `sudo su -` which is recommended over `sudo su` for most everyday purposes.

Comment: +1 for the sudo -i.  I was about to add that as a comment to the question.

Comment: @Sparr why is sudo -i recommended over sudo su - which is recommended over sudo su? please.  Thanks.

Comment: From the `man su` page.  "The optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly."  Obvious advantage there.  `sudo -i` vs `sudo su -`?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the file `/etc/sudoers`. It has been configured to allow your user account to execute `su` (and perhaps other commands) as root under sudo without needing a password. And when run as root, `su` does not prompt for authentication.

This can be done either on a per-account basis or by group membership. (Typically, by membership in the `wheel` group.)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo su` lets you use the password for `demo@PHP_DEV_57` to get a root terminal (as long as you're listed in the `sudoers` file).  `su` makes you use the password for `root@PHP_DEV_57` (which may or may not exist or be known) to get a root terminal.