# What's the difference between sudo su - postgres and sudo -u postgres?

Tags: postgresql, shell, sudo, su

PostgreSQL users peer authentication on unix sockets by default, where the unix user must be the same as the PostgreSQL user. So people frequently use `su` or `sudo` to become the `postgres` superuser.

I often see people using constructs like:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

rather than

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

and I'm wondering why. Similarly, I've seen:

```
sudo su - postgres -c psql
```

instead of

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Without the leading `sudo` the `su` versions would make some sense if you were on an old platform without `sudo`. But why on a less than prehisoric UNIX or Linux would you use `sudo su` ?

Comment: Related on sister site, DBA Stack Exchange: [*Switch user to 'postgres' user on macOS results in “su: Sorry” error*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221043/19079)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## Forget `sudo su`

There is no benefit to using `sudo su`, it's an anachronistic habit from when people were used to using `su`. People started tacking `sudo` in front when Linux distros stopped setting a root password and made `sudo` the only way to access the root account. Rather than change their habits, they just used `sudo su`. (I was one of them until relatively recently when using boxes with `sudoers` configs forced me to change my habit).

## Use `sudo -u`

For a login shell, `sudo -u postgres -i` is preferable to `sudo su - postgres`. It doesn't require that the user have root access in `/etc/sudoers`, they only need the right to become user `postgres`. It also lets you enforce better access controls.

For command execution

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT 1"
```

is superior to the alternative:

```
sudo su - postgres -c "psql -c \"SELECT 1\""
```

in that you don't have to double-escape quotes and other shell metacharacters as well as the other security advantages of not needing root. You'll probably accidentally land up writing:

```
sudo su - postgres -c psql -c "SELECT 1"
```

sometimes, which won't work properly.

Finally, it's way easier to set environment variables via `sudo`, e.g.

```
sudo PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/testcluster
```

than via `su`. (Here, the `PATH` setting is required so that `initdb` can find the correct `postgres` executable).

So. Forget the `su` command exists. You don't need it anymore. To break the habit, alias it to something that'll print an error. (Some init and package setup scripts still use `su` so you can't remove it, though).

See also:

- [What's the difference between "sudo su -" and "sudo -i"?](https://serverfault.com/q/469539/102814)
- [What's the magic of the "sudo su"?](https://serverfault.com/q/211145/102814)
- [What is the difference between sudo -i and sudo su -](https://serverfault.com/q/359856/102814)